# Vlan Extension vs VPLS + need understanding

Tags: routing, vlan, mpls, network-core, vpls

I have tried to find the answer online and I was trying to make sure my understanding is correct. So if someone can point me to the correct path please do.

My understanding of vlan extension are vlans that are created on switches (l2 or l3) then configure a trunk and allow the vlans to travel on it. (Please correct it if I am failing to understand it)

Will customers have a better experience on a network with VPLS connection? I believe it is also good for the router as it reduces workload?

Is it worth it to break down a network thats already using vlan extensions to put up vpls ?

I would like others to explain these few points to me.

thanks

EDIT:
[image]

Normally my topology is like this, the bgp is ok I am going to connect the 3 l3 switches and configure them with iBGP between them. Then I will run MPLS on the L3 switches. since the organization is extending vlan 110 all the way to the gpon I was thinking that If I can configure VPLS it will improve the way the services are used on the network, as as far as I see its layer 2 configuration being done from the L3switches all the way to the gpon equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to extend VLANs.  Trunks are just one way. VPLS is another. The best method to use depends on several factors, most notably, the type of media that link the two locations, the distance, whether the link is under your control, etc.

Besides the concerns about reliability, cost, etc., you also have to consider the impact of spanning tree, flooding, loops, storms, etc.  Each method has different ways of mitigating these issues.

To answer your specific question about VPLS, we would need to know a lot more information.  A diagram would be useful, along with some idea of traffic flows, and the kinds of hosts on both ends.

Comment: Hello I did the necessary changes could you now have a look. , from the GPON equipment routers are installed at client premises and give FTTH services.

Comment: I don't think your customers will have a better experience, but you might find it to be more flexible and faster to provision.

Comment: ah ok, thanks I will keep this in mind. I always thought that the network would be "healthier" because MPLS uses labels so it might reduce load on the routers/l3 switches and also provide faster service.